# Condition checking in DataWeave component

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

### Input XML:

```
 <Orders>
 <Order>
   <sample id="a">23435</sample>
   .
   .
   .
  <sample id="x">D123</sample>
     .
      .
  <sample id="y">5346</sample>
  <sample id="z"></sample>
  .
  .
  </Order>
 <Order>
   <sample id="a">23435</sample>
   .
   .
   .
  <sample id="x">D345</sample>
     .
      .
  <sample id="y">5346</sample>
  <sample id="z">D217</sample>
  .
  .
  </Order>
 <Order>
   <sample id="a">23435</sample>
   .
   .
   .
  <sample id="x">D1235</sample>
     .
      .
  <sample id="y">5346</sample>
  <sample id="z"></sample>
  .
  .
  </Order>
```

### Requirement:

If 'sample' element with attribute='z' has no value then I need to map 'sample' element with attribute 'x' to 'ProId'; else if it has value, then I should not pass any value to 'ProFeed' map.   (For each 'Order' element I need to create one 'ProFeed' map)

### Output:

```
 [ProFeed={ProId="",Lang="eng",CatId="AU"},ProFeed={ProId="",Lang="eng",CatId="AU"},ProFeed={ProId="",Lang="eng",CatId="AU"}]
```

DataWeave config:

```
%input application/xml 
%output application/java
.(some configuration code)
.
.
```

Please help me out in the configuration of DataWeave component.

Comment: Please do comment incase you need any clarification in the requirement. I am very new to dataweave.

Comment: Can I use this in the configuration instead? %input application/xml 
%output application/json

Comment: @RalphRimorin

Please post your configuration, I can verify if it works.

Comment: Please answer this as it is one of important requirement for me

Comment: Are you still there? Sorry I didn't rreply.

Comment: @RalphRimorin


Yess Ralph.  I cannt fetch the value of sample element with attribute "x", when doing condition check for "sample" element with attribute "z". Also, You are doing condition check if attribute "z" is  present or not. But my scenario is if value is present in corresponding element. I hope now you understand the scenario. Anyways I have acheived the solution for this scenario. But only part of the condition check i am doing inside dataweave. Rest part condition check I am doing outside Dataweave. Thanks for you time :) .

Comment: no problem. Dataweave is still pre mature but very promising on its future capabilities.

Comment: Issue has been resolved thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try enhancing this:

[image]

The only problem here is otherwise $, which should able to return the value of the sample with attribute "x". I can't figure how to nested the when/otherwise

Comment: You get a 1+ because while I didn't have the same question, your sample helped me solve mine.

Answer (score 0):

The below should be your logic . 
Fill it for your scenario

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---

payload.Orders map {
  ProId: $.id when $.@id != null otherwise $.sample,
  .....
}
```

Comment: I m not sure you understood the requirement. I have commented once again regarding the requirement. Also as per $ you referred, it will be pointing to Order element, I believe

Comment: I think that is the basis of using conditions can you apply similar for your solution and then let me know if it worked ? It may not be a complete script that you can copy and paste and get it work for the input you have but modifications to your component should do